# jquery find text inside <td>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm playing around with some selectors, and I'm hitting a wall with selecting Text inside a  cell.

Here's a simple attempt I'm making.

```
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>First Name</td>
     <td>*required</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the class for that cell to be "red" - if the string "*required" is found.

Here's my attempt at the jquery:

```
$("td:contains('*required')").addClass("red");
```

It's causing all cells to apply that class, it seems.
Any better ways to look for specific text?

Comment: As far I can see it's working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/nY29Q/

Comment: This works for me.  Could you link to/post on http://jsfiddle.net the code that you are actually using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/g5Vqn/), keep in mind that any *parent* `<td>` *also* contains that text though, to do an exact match do this:

```
$("td").filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == '*required'; })
       .addClass("red");
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/g5Vqn/1/).

Comment: That's an interesting site.  I may have to bookmark it!
The code I am using is working, when I place it on a simple site, which means I must have something else working against me.  gotta do some more investigating.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `$.text()` function -- is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @lonesomeday - nope, not really, it's `Sizzle.getText()` underneath, it's just a cheaper way of doing `$(this).text()` without the jQuery object creation cost.

Comment: Sneaky. Nice, but definitely sneaky!

Answer (score 5):

You could always just use `$.filter()`, where only elements that the callback returns true for are included in the selection.  For example:

```
$('td').filter(function(i) {
    $(this).html().indexOf('*required') >= 0;
});
```

Also: you'll want to be more specific with your selector - for efficiency, and also because of Nick's answer.  Though if you're considering efficiency, you're better off not using a method that uses a callback in the first place. :)

As far as selectors go, consider using `$('#tableID > tr > td')...` or something similar.

Answer (score -2):

You should not be using JavaScript to do this. What you should be using is a CSS class:

```
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>First Name</td>
     <td class="required">*required</td>
  </tr>
</table> 


<style type="text/css">
td.required {
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think the point is that cell doesn't have the class to begin with.

Comment: Don't you have control over the markup? How would you be in the position to write the JavaScript but not be able to use CSS appropriately? Are you just experimenting with selectors as a learning exercise?

Comment: Snickers, imagine a table with many rows. I'm talking hundreds of rows. Some cells have specific text inside, like "*required", or "*optional", or "recommended".
Rather than applying a class to each cell, which would take time and get tedious, the magic of jquery can do it for me.