# How loop each table and write the status at run time using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The below code helps to get the number of rows in each table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".assertionTable").each(function(){

       var test=$(this).find("tr").length;
        document.write(test);

    });

});
```

But, I had an another issue. I just wanna get the cell value and If the cell contains "FAILED" keyword then it needs to write the status at runtime. Please find the sample code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".assertionTable").each(function(){

       var test=$(this).find("tr td:last-child").is(':contains("FAILED")'); //Just assume that I have two table in a page, and one table contains "FAILED", and other table not contains that keyword. So It returns true, false in output console which is expected.
```

Based on that value I just need to write the main status as PASSED or FAILED. 
Just assume that each table has it's own ".mainStatus" class.

```
       if(test==true)
       {
           $(".mainStatus").html("FAILED");
       }
        else
        {
         $(".mainStatus").html("PASSED");   
        }

    });

});
```

Unfortunately, Its not working. I just wanna try my self that's what I posted the query which is similar to my issue. I hope you can understand and help me out.

I don't have any id attribute, I just wanna done this by using only class.

Please help me out. Thanks in advanced.

Please find more info: [How to iterate the elements using index in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176283/how-to-iterate-the-elements-using-index-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment52238694_32176283)

-Sasi

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073427/jquery-find-text-inside-td

Comment: Why don't you just do this  -> `var test=$(this).find("tr td:last-child").text();`

Comment: `.find("tr td:last-child")` this will find last `td`, does those word exist on that part?

Comment: Yes, It works as expected. But the problem here to write the status into respective table. I have n number of table in a page and has same class name.Based on the keyword in table I need to write the div status into respective table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".assertionTable").each(function(){

       var test=$(this).find("tr td:last-child").is(':contains("FAILED")');

      var divassertiondatTable = $(this).parent();
      var prevTestStatusDiv = divassertiondatTable.prev(".teststatus");

      if(test==true)
      {
           $(prevTestStatusDiv).find(".status").html("FAILED");
      }
      else
      {
          $(prevTestStatusDiv).find(".status").html("PASSED");   
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: I hope that find is used to search the descendant element. But, here case is different. I will post the sample html code which could be help you to assume my requirement.    <div class="mainStatus"></div> //empty tag and it has to write at run time. <div class="assertionTable"><table><tr><td>...all my table code herer...</td></tr></table></div>  I just wanna write the status in mainStatus class as per the table content. If table has "FAILED" keyword in td:last-child then It has to log as FAILED. I have n number of table as similar like this. I hope my explanation is clear now.  -Sasi

Comment: sorry SKumar. But I am unable to visualize the full HTML structure. Could you please post it so that I can take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know SKumar, that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checkStatus = function(elements){
        elements.each(function(){
            //check it contains the word
            if($(this).is(':contains("FAILED")')){
                //Empty the container and then add dynamic container
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).append('<div class="mainStatus">PASSED</div>');
            }
        })
    };
    $(".assertionTable").each(function(){
        checkStatus($(this).find("tr td:last-child"));
    });
});
```

Please let me know if you still facing any issue.